# animating the ASP Menu using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
Home    Folio     About
        - menu1     shop
        - menu2     More - a
                         - b
```

The asp navigation menu looks something like this and I would like to apply the slideDown effect for submenus when hovered over Folio, About and More.

Tried the below, but it slides all 3 submenus when hovered over Folio or About

```
$(".has-popup a").hover(function(){
$("ul.dynamic").slideDown("slow");
});
```

The Menu control adds its own css classes making it even more difficult.

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="level1 static">
    <li class="static">
      <a class="level1 selected static">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="has-popup static">
      <a class="static">Folio</a>
      <ul class="level2 dynamic">
        <li class="dynamic"> <a class="level2 dynamic">menu1</a></li>
```

Any advice, how to go ahead? (it's so hard to type. Dont have the option to paste).

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
$("ul.dynamic").slideDown("slow");
```

is targetting all `ul`s with the class `dynamic`. You only need to target the `ul` which is inside the hovered menu `a`:

```
$(".has-popup").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("ul.dynamic").first().stop().slideDown("fast");
}, function() { 
    $(this).find("ul.dynamic").first().stop().slideUp("fast");
});
```

**Update**:

After reading your comments, I created a quick and dirty fiddle to help you. And have rectified the above code accordingly.

See fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/w798Z/**

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ruby : sorry, i did a mistake. it is `next` instead of `find`. updated the answer.

Comment: No Probs.It does scroll now, but it does for all the submenus. Just like it did for my code.

Comment: @Ruby : could you please post the complete generated markup of the menu. i think i might be missing layout of other sub-menus.

Comment: Its the same as in question. Sorry, its very lengthy, and I dont have the option to Paste. But Thank you anyways.

Comment: @Ruby: thanks for the patience. i have updated the answer with a fiddle to show how it works with your sample.

Comment: @abhitalks.The fiddle looks similar to what is generated for my menu.But unfortunately it disnt even apply the effect. I dont understand why they make such complicated controls. Thanks a lot for ur effort.I m leaving this.